# Kendo version updation throws an error "kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource is not a constructor"

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, scheduler, kendo-scheduler

I am trying to use kendo.all.min.js version **Kendo UI v2017.2.504** instead of **Kendo UI v2015.1.429**

I have implemented Kendo Scheduler for which Iam creating a datasource using kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource object

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
                data: GetSchedulerDataSource(),
.............
```

I am facing an error in browser console which wasn't exists when I was using old version.

**Uncaught TypeError: kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource is not a constructor**

Please help.

Comment: You will have to show your code as simply instantiating a SchedulerDataSource in 2017.2.504 does not throw the error(see http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/OKEhe).

Comment: What's the content of `GetSchedulerDataSource()`? What are the other members of the object you supply to the `SchedulerDataSource` constructor besides `data`?